# Is there an "integration by parts" method in $L^2[0,1]$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I would like to know if my approach for some exercise I was trying to solve is right:

Let $T: L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ be defined pointwise as $Tf(x) := \int_0^xf(t)dt$, and consider $S:L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ defined pointwise by $Sg(y) = \int_y^1g(y)dy$. Prove that $S = T^*$.

My approach was the following:

Since $\mathcal{C}^0[0,1]$ is a dense subset of $L^2[0,1]$ (Lusin's Theorem), given any element $f,g\in L^2[0,1]$ we could take sequences of continuous functions (which we can integrate by parts) $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$.

Calculating $\langle Tf_n, g_n \rangle = \int_0^1(\int_0^xf_n(t)dt)g_n(x)dx$, and integrating by parts with $u = \int_0^xf_n(t)dt$ and $dv = g_n(x)dx$, we get $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\int_0^1g_n(x)dx - \int_0^1(\int_0^xg_n(t)dt)f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1f_n(x)\left[\int_0^1g_n(y)dy - \int_0^xg_n(t)dt\right] = \int_0^1f_n(x)(\int_x^1g_n(y)dy)dx = \langle f_n,Sg_n\rangle$.

Given that $\langle Tf_n, g_n \rangle = \langle f_n,Sg_n\rangle$, for all continuous functions, then $\langle Tf_n,g_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle Tf,g\rangle$, since the inner product is continuous, we get $\langle Tf,g\rangle = \langle f,Sg\rangle$.

But I'm wondering if it is correct, since it basically says that there is an "integration by parts" method in $L^2[0,1]$, which is something I haven't seen anywhere.

(I know that the result is true because one can use Fubini's Theorem, and we can solve changing the order of the integrands, since the domain is a triangle, but I would like to know if the other approach is valid)

Comment: Yes, it's correct.